# Hibernate HQL Map query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

i have a class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "days")
public class DayEntry {

@Expose
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
.
.
@Expose
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "day_item_hours")
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "item_id")
@Column(name = "hours")
private Map<Item, Double> itemsHours;
.
.
}
```

I need to get from DB all **DayEntries** which contain specific **Item** in **itemHours** field.

I tried:

```
private final String FIND_BY_ACTIVITY = "from DayEntry d where :activity in index(d.itemsHours)";
@Override
public Collection<DayEntry> findByActivity(Item activity) {
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(FIND_BY_ACTIVITY);
    query.setParameter("activity", activity);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

And get this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 75 [from ua.siemens.dbtool.model.timesheet.DayEntry d where :activity in index(d.itemsHours)]] with root cause
 org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 75 [from ua.siemens.dbtool.model.timesheet.DayEntry d where :activity in index(d.itemsHours)]
```

Not sure how to handle this.
Thanks!

**UPDATE**

For the moment i ended up with plain SQL Query:

```
    private final String FIND_BY_ACTIVITY = "SELECT * FROM days where id = (SELECT DayEntry_id from day_item_hours where day_item_hours.item_id = :activityId)";

@Override
public Collection<DayEntry> findByActivity(Item activity) {
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(FIND_BY_ACTIVITY_ID, DayEntry.class);
    query.setParameter("activityId", activity.getId());
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

but still i wonder how to do it with HQL.

Comment: index() returns the inex of an element in an ordered list. You want the key in a Map. The function for that is key().